# How to read Spring Boot application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-boot

I've just read documentation about external config and I found I can easily access application.properties using:

```
@Component
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;

    // ...

}
```

But I want to add property to the class, that is not Spring component (I initialize it using **new**).

I want to apply it here:

```
public class PageWrapper<T> {

private int maxButtonQuantity = **I want to put here the property from file**;
private Page<T> page;
private List<PageItem> buttons;
private int currentNumber;
private String url;
...
}
```

**PageWrapper** is not a Spring Bean class - it's not "floating" in Spring container. I initialize it in some controller manually - using **new** operator

Is there any way to access it in a simple way, that I don't have to use the container?

Comment: could you explain more about the property that you are adding, it is not clear when you say that you initialize by using new.  You could show the code that describes the property.

Comment: @faljbour - I added explanation

Comment: you may want to pass he property to the PageWrapper class in the constructor or add a set method in it.  Get the value in the controller class then pass it to the PageWrapper

Comment: @faljbour you should write this as an answer

Comment: sure, I just did @ci_ , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the PageWrapper class is instantiated in the controller, you can get the property, just pass it in a method as you see below, or you can pass it in the constructor of the PageWrapper class.

```
    @Configuration
    @Controller
    public class MyController 
    {

      @Value("${name}")
      private String name;

      @Value("${maxButtonQuantity}")
      private int maxButtonQuantity;

      ................

     //* pass the value to PageWrapper after you instantiate it,
     pageWrapper.setMaxButtonQuantity(maxButtonQuantity);

    }

    public class PageWrapper<T> {

      private int maxButtonQuantity = **I want to put here the property from file**;
      private Page<T> page;
      private List<PageItem> buttons;
      private int currentNumber;
      private String url;

      public void setMaxButtonQuantity(int maxButtonQuantity)
      {
        this.maxButtonQuantity = maxButtonQuantity;
      }

    }
```